# Display the row by row wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

table1

```
ID Value

101 100
102 200
103 500
```

I have only 3 row in the table.  I want to make in row wise view

Expected Output

```
101 102 103
100 200 500
```

How to make a select query for the above condition.

Need Query Help

Comment: output result is a table? How titles `ID` and `Value` should be displayed ?

Comment: ID and Value mentioned for the reference.....

Comment: What are `101`, `102`, `103` in the results? Are they column names or are they values in a row (specifically the first row, possibly)?

Answer (score 1):

If you defenitely know which values you have in `ID` column you can use query like this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id_101) AS id_101,
    MAX(id_102) AS id_102,
    MAX(id_103) AS id_103
FROM (
SELECT
    1 AS aux,
    CASE WHEN ID = 101 THEN val ELSE null END AS id_101,
    CASE WHEN ID = 102 THEN val ELSE null END AS id_102,
    CASE WHEN ID = 103 THEN val ELSE null END AS id_103
FROM table1
) AS t(aux, id_101, id_102, id_103)
GROUP BY t.aux;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 101, 102, 103 is a column names you can rotate table usign PIVOT:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT id, value
 FROM @data1
) p
PIVOT (SUM(value) FOR [id] IN ([101], [102], [103])) AS pvt
```

[image]

---

Prepare data:

```
DECLARE @data1 TABLE(id int, value INT)
INSERT INTO @data1 VALUES(101, 100)
INSERT INTO @data1 VALUES(102, 200)
INSERT INTO @data1 VALUES(103, 500)
```

Comment: Pivot is sql server 2008, OP is using 2000